# Whats the right swagger tool/plugin to generate Swagger 2.0 jsons out of JaxRS annoations which works with ANT?

Tags: ant, jax-rs, swagger-2.0

We use Apache Ant for our project build and were thinking of extending the same for getting swagger 2.0 specs .json generated for our REST API docs. I found an ant task : https://github.com/cstroe/swagger-ant-task 
which would invoke the same swagger core maven plugin, but some dependency jars have been changed in the github package due to which I am getting 'No Such Method' Exception for getApiInfo() method in ApiSourceInfo.java. 
We cannot use maven just for generating API docs. I needed some help in finding a way by which I can use swagger core tool of generating docs using swagger annotations in the API definition file. Using ant wrapper for the maven plugin was one way but I am not not able to leverage it. Is there any other workaround?

Or to frame it otherwise, whats the right swagger tool/plugin to generate Swagger 2.0 jsons out of JaxRS annoations which works with ANT.
 Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm working figuring this out as well.   My first approach was that I found a github project with some amount of activity that does this by providing a Javadoc doclet - that seemed like a great application of custom doclets.

https://github.com/conorroche/swagger-doclet

I think the project is solid, but this approach just didn't seem appropriate for my project in that I couldn't find a non-DRY way to replicate all the inputs to the doclet.    

The approach I'm working on now is that I'm told that Maven plugins can be invoked from Ant.